# Create common layers for two different docker images

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile

When I create docker image on my local and use `docker inspect`,  I got following layers

```
"Layers": [
   "sha256:721384ec99e56bc06202a738722bcb4b8254b9bbd71c43ab7ad0d9e773ced7ac",
   "sha256:5e6abd2adb12979c5c361f46711677590540cb8955974ad318ba2fdff6491811",
   "sha256:9b9411b58604d49fd1283430d3bbdbc238b3d25b16c729aac49e9158eba8da69",
   "sha256:fa51dce368709d6994484c6f87fd465eae2dbe6ae7876f6fe4adc17283ad72ed",
   "sha256:2975210efdc28244070b0fede0d3f233a21b096907e54235cd34a6ca4f86e4bc"
]
```

what I need to do if I want same layers except only one layer for different image?
meaning,  I want below layers only with combination of different layers in another image.

```
"sha256:5e6abd2adb12979c5c361f46711677590540cb8955974ad318ba2fdff6491811",
"sha256:9b9411b58604d49fd1283430d3bbdbc238b3d25b16c729aac49e9158eba8da69",
"sha256:fa51dce368709d6994484c6f87fd465eae2dbe6ae7876f6fe4adc17283ad72ed",
"sha256:2975210efdc28244070b0fede0d3f233a21b096907e54235cd34a6ca4f86e4bc"
```

I tried using same layers in dockerfile but that did not work. These are the layers I used

Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk update
RUN echo  "test message"
RUN apk add curl
RUN apk add wget
RUN apk add vim
```

I want two different images with common layers except the first layer. please help.

Comment: Do you have Dockerfiles that create these images?  What do you want to be shared?  A picture might be a little clearer than a list of SHA256 hashes.

Comment: You can build an image only with the shared layers and use that as base for your two images.

Comment: Actually I want common layerids for two images having different base image. Any samples I can get that would be helpful. When I am changing base image then immediately layerdigestids of remaining layers are changing. So I want two different images having common layers except the first one [ base image ] Is that possible ?

Comment: This is the image : https://ibb.co/BGXyxMV  shows two images having common layers but showing different digest id